# Есть какой-то способ автоматически обновить содержимое TreeView или ComboBox при изменении (переименовании) элемента?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, combobox

Есть какой-то способ автоматически обновить содержимое TreeView или ComboBox при изменении (переименовании) элемента?

Без прямого указывания каждый раз в каждой функции о необходимости обновить после изменения.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под переименованием элемента, и о каком, собственно, элементе идёт речь? Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Используйте INotifyPropertyChanged.